# Is it possible to display special characters such as space, tab etc. when printing a string?

Tags: python, string, repr

For example I have a string

```
line = r'I like cakes'
```

Is it possible to print it like this?

```
 I\s like\s cakes
```

`repr()` is not working in this case

Comment: Wouldn't you want `"I\slike\scakes"`? repr isn't working because the `\s` is not a recognised Python string escape sequence.

Comment: you just want `replace` ? you don't need to ask a question for that...

Comment: I am asking this because I have a table represented as a string, so the columns are fixed width, but the data in them are not. So I just wanted to display those kind of symbols to understand how to write a code to convert it to pandas df.

Comment: I'm unsure why that would be necessary, which makes me wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Surely the real problem is how to get that table into a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a dictionary of replacements for each of the characters you wanted to replace.

```
rep_dict = {' ': '\s', '\n': '\\n', '\t': '\\t'}
```

The the following function will perform the necessary replacement:

```
def quote(s):
    return "".join(repr_dict.get(c, c) for c in s)
```

The `repr_dict.get` call tries to look up the character in the dictionary, and uses the character itself as the default value for failed lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by replacing spaces with the intended sequence:

```py
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> line = r'I like cakes'
>>> print(line.replace(" ", "\s "))
I\s like\s cakes
```

To also support tabs you could use:

```py
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> line = "I like\tcakes"
>>> print(line)
I like  cakes
>>> print(line.replace(" ", "\s ").replace("\t", "\\t"))
I\s like\tcakes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by [Python String replace() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
line = r'I like cakes'    
print(line.replace(" ", "\s "))
```

OUTPUT:

```
I\s like\s cakes
```